# Theories with countably many countable models

Tags: model-theory, big-list

Having another question in mind (which is not yet fully worked out, but will come soon) I'd like to gather some examples of (interesting)

> **theories with countably many countable models**

("Countably many models" means "countably many *isomorphism classes* of models".)

Comment: Here is a somewhat non-trivial example, in that the verification takes some work. Let $T$ be the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$. Any model is isomorphic to the algebraic numbers with $0,1,2,\dots,\omega$ algebraicaly independent transcendentals added.

Comment: By Baldwin-Lachlan Theorem any uncountably categorical theory has either 1 or $\aleph_0$ countable models.

Comment: Among the examples given by Levon's comment are not only the one given by André Nicolas but also (1) the theory of divisible, torsion-free, abelian groups and (2) the theory of a permutation without (finite) cycles. If you allow incomplete theories, there are even simpler examples, like the theory that has one unary predicate and no axioms.

Comment: Discrete linear orders, I think?  But I'm actually not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @RichardRast There are continuum many nonisomorphic countable discrete linear orders. Think of such an order as a lot of copies of $\mathbb Z$ arranged relative to each other in some linear order. That order, in turn, can consist of some finite blocks separated by dense blocks. By varying the sizes of the finite blocks, you can get lots of nonisomorphic examples.

Comment: Yeah, in fact they're Borel-complete.  Embarrassing that I wrote that ...

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're going for a big list?  Here are several:

- Many strongly minimal theories (e.g. $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces, algebraically closed fields of a fixed characteristic)
- More generally, any $\aleph_1$-categorical theory which is not also $\aleph_0$-categorical.
- Shelah has an $\omega$-stable example with $\textrm{ENI}$-depth two (so is not $\aleph_1$-categorical) which has exactly $\aleph_0$-many countable models, which is complicated to describe (see Section 4 of Chapter 18 of Baldwin's stability theory book)

Some interesting nonexamples:

- O-minimal theories have either finitely many or continuum-many countable models (theorem of L. Mayer) and both cases are possible
- Linear order with countably many unary predicates attached have the same property (theorem of M. Rubin) and both cases are possible

It is somewhat interesting that the uncountable models of such a theory are uninteresting in the following sense: every model of such a theory (of any cardinality) is back-and-forth equivalent to a countable model.

This means there is no definable behavior, using any $L_{\infty\omega}$-formula you like, which can occur on any model which does not occur on a countable model.